# Incorrect placement of selector using Polymer dom-if

Tags: javascript, dom, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to use a conditional template to show *additional content* if the user supplies an attribute to a custom element.

```
<dom-module id="demo-element">
    <template>
        <div>
            <template is="dom-if" if="{{icon}}">
                <i class="{{icon}} icon"></i>
            </template>
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'demo-element',

            properties: {
                icon: { type: String }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I call the custom element as follows:

```
 <demo-element icon="protected">Title</demo-element>
```

When I inspect the rendered result in the browser, I see:

```
<demo-element icon="protect">
    <div class="foo style-scope demo-element protect">
        <i class="style-scope demo-element"></i>
        <template is="dom-if" class="style-scope demo-element"></template>
        Title
    </div>
</demo-element>
```

but I should see:

```
<demo-element icon="protect">
    <div class="foo style-scope demo-element">
        <i class="protect icon style-scope demo-element"></i>
        <template is="dom-if" class="style-scope demo-element"></template>
        Title
    </div>
</demo-element>
```

Based on what the [documentation says](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-if), this approach should work. Can someone clarify why this is happening and how to do this correctly?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Clarified, see update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
<i class$="{{icon}} icon"
```

or

```
<i class$="[[icon]] icon"
```

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#native-binding